# Is It Possible To Look at Multiple Groupings of Objects in a JSON file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I'm looking to make a leveling system without using a database. Yes I know a database is the better way to go but the leveling system is just for my own server which doesn't have a large amount of people talking and I haven't learned how to use databases and integrate them so I want to do something smaller that I understand for now.

Right now I have it set up to hold a level and exp for anyone that sends a message. I was hoping instead of doing a bunch of "if else" statements, I could use another JSON file to store the exp required for each level. I wanted to set it up like so

```
{
   "level": 2,
   "expRequired": 100
},

{
   "level": 3,
   "expRequired": 300
}
```

Is there a way I could use this method and check through each grouping and compare it to the message author's current exp? Something like

```
if (memberExp[message.author.id].exp == levels.expRequired) {
   memberExp[message.author.id].level = levels.level
}
```

Comment: I think the issue here is that you need to expand on what the level will gate. i.e. give a more full example of how the level `enable` or `disable` a feature and what that feature is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question, the levels could easily be an array (in a JSON file):

```
levels : [0, 100, 300, 1000, 5000]
```

Then you can check the exp against the lowest entry that it matches, and that will be your level

```
for(let i = 0; i < levels.length; i++) {
    if (memberExp[message.author.id].exp > levels[i]) {
        memberExp[message.author.id].level = i
    } 
}
```

UPDATE

I added a level check so you can see how many levels you gained

```
// remember the old level
let previousLevel = memberExp[message.author.id].level

// level up according to xp
for(let i = 0; i < levels.length; i++) {
    if (memberExp[message.author.id].exp > levels[i]) {
        memberExp[message.author.id].level = i
    } 
}

// check how many levels we gained
let amountGained = memberExp[message.author.id].level - previousLevel

// if we gained more than 0 we can display a message
if(amountGained > 0) {
    console.log(`Congrats! You gained ${amountGained} levels!`)
}
```

Comment: The only issue I have with this method is that it would start the levels off at level 0 until they hit 100 exp right? Because if they have 50 exp they're only greater than levels[0] which would make memberExp[message.author.id].level = 0 wouldn't it? I'm multi tasking hard right now so my brain isn't thinking properly so apologies if I'm not understanding correctly.

Comment: Never mind stupid me. I just have to add 1 to x to have it equal the right level. Thanks!

Comment: Exactly! It's just because arrays start counting at 0. If someone is level 0 you can display "1" in the interface.

Comment: Ok so while this works to getting the level, I want to also congratulate the person when they level up. But I can't seemt o figure out how to do that. If I put it in the for loop, it displays every level-up up to my current level. I'm not sure how I would check it outside of the for loop.

Comment: You could compare the `memberExp[message.author.id].level` before and after the `for` loop. If it's higher afterwards then the player gained a level and you can congratulate him/her!

Comment: I hate that I have to ask this but how would I do that? I’ve been trying to figure out for a week now and I have no clue how to get it to work. This for loop is both hurting and helping since it’s not checking to see if it’s at 1 specific threshold and instead it sees every level before it as well.

Comment: I added a comparison between the old and the new level!

Comment: Dude you are seriously a life saver thank you so much for your help. That was really the hardest part of this whole thing so to see it working now makes me super happy and excited.

Comment: Good luck with the game!